# it is compulsorry whenever you declare Hashmap than we will pass on two Argument?

Tags: android

it is compulsory whenever you declare Hashmap than we will pass on two Argument?
like 
HashMap atts = obj.getParams();

Comment: Yes, because its syntax is developer like that. `Key` and `Value`

Comment: yes it is based on Key and value pair so it's compulsory

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because it consists of key - value pair.
[HashMap Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

there must be some mechanism in HashMap to store this key value pair. see the link http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/